# Is using na.approx depending on dynamical date range (timeframe) possible?

Tags: r

does anyone know if it is possible to use the na.approx function to interpolate depending on a varying timeframe ?

Let's suggest we have a df like (the real df has over 5'000 rows):

```
Date, Value
2022-05-01, 6
2022-05-02, 5
2022-05-03, NA
2022-05-06, NA
2022-05-07, 14
2022-05-08, 15
2022-05-09, NA
2022-05-10, 67
```

I want to conduct an linear interpolation depending on the date range. For example the two NA's at beginning: 1) 14-5 = 9, 2) Counting the days from 2022-05-02 until 2022-05-06 = 5 days, so we divide 3) 9/5 = 1.8.
Value for NA at 2022-05-03 is 6.8 and for 2022-05-06 is 8.6.

Second example at 2022-05-09: 1) 67-15 = 52, 2) 2022-05-08 until 2022-05-10 = 3 days, 3) 52/3  = 17.33333. Value for NA at 2022-05-09 is 32.33333 (= 15 + 17.33333)

Is this possible to conduct it with the na.approx function? If not, how can I approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the data frame `DF` defined reproducibly in the Note at the end, we see that what is asked for, i.e. linear interpolation with respect to `Date`, is what you get (after correcting the [calculations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation) in the question) if you apply `na.approx` to a zoo series:

```
library(zoo)

z <- read.zoo(DF)
na.approx(z)
## 2022-05-01 2022-05-02 2022-05-03 2022-05-06 2022-05-07 2022-05-08 2022-05-09 
##        6.0        5.0        6.8       12.2       14.0       15.0       41.0 
## 2022-05-10 
##       67.0
```

or in terms of the original data frame we can use the `x=` argument of `na.approx` to specify that interpolation is with respect to `Date`.

```
DF$Date <- as.Date(DF$Date)
transform(DF, Value = na.approx(Value, Date, na.rm = FALSE))
##         Date Value
## 1 2022-05-01   6.0
## 2 2022-05-02   5.0
## 3 2022-05-03   6.8
## 4 2022-05-06  12.2
## 5 2022-05-07  14.0
## 6 2022-05-08  15.0
## 7 2022-05-09  41.0
## 8 2022-05-10  67.0
```

Suggest you review the documentation using `?na.approx` from R.

### Note

```
Lines <- "Date, Value
2022-05-01, 6
2022-05-02, 5
2022-05-03, NA
2022-05-06, NA
2022-05-07, 14
2022-05-08, 15
2022-05-09, NA
2022-05-10, 67"
DF <- read.csv(text = Lines, strip.white = TRUE)
```

Comment: Ah so it was just straight up linear interpolation? That wasn't really clear in the Q as it says the value for 2022-05-06 is 8.6 not 12.2. Oh well, nice answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I can do it with a bit of a slog, but I may need some help with the date diffs. For the first case there's 5 days between 02/05 & 07/05. In the second there's 2 days, not 3 between 08/05 & 10/05. Have I missed something? :)

Code below:

```
# get data into required shape, and using data.table package
df <- read.table(text="
Date, Value
2022-05-01, 6
2022-05-02, 5
2022-05-03, NA
2022-05-06, NA
2022-05-07, 14
2022-05-08, 15
2022-05-09, NA
2022-05-10, 67
", header=T)
library(data.table)
library(zoo)
library(lubridate)
dt <- as.data.table(df)
dt[, Date := lubridate::ymd(gsub(",","",`Date.`))]
setorder(dt, Date)

# first step, fill in to get the starting value
dt[, Value2 := zoo::na.locf0(Value)]

# group together the rows, only really interested in the NA ones, 
# ensuring they are grouped together. rleid makes a group where it finds new values
dt[, Group := rleid(is.na(Value))]
# find the value after the NA
dt[, ValueNext := shift(Value2, n=1, type="lead")]
# find the dates before and after the NA period
dt[, DatePre := shift(Date, n=1, type="lag")]
dt[, DateNext := shift(Date, n=1, type="lead")]
# find the differences in the values & dates
dt[, ValueDiff := ValueNext[.N]-Value2[1], by=Group]
dt[, DateDiff := as.integer(DateNext[.N]-DatePre[1]), by=Group]
# divide through to get the addition
dt[, ValueAdd := ValueDiff/DateDiff]
# by group, use cumulative sum to add to the starting value
dt[, ValueOut := Value2+cumsum(ValueAdd), by=Group]
# we only care about NA groups, so revert back to original value for other
# cases
dt[!is.na(Value), ValueOut := Value]

# check the NA rows
# ! only difference is I get 2 as the date diff for 2022-05-09, not 3
dt[is.na(Value),]

# Final output
dt[, .(Date, Value, ValueOut)]
```